# sendmail with crontab using default from and to address

Tags: cron, sendmail

When I run sendmail with crontab getting below logs in mail.log

```
2020-07-17T02:50:12.431886-07:00 localhost postfix/qmgr[1371]: 681EC1FFEF: from=<nramasurbramanian@localhost>, size=777, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2020-07-17T02:50:12.435570-07:00 localhost postfix/local[26936]: 681EC1FFEF: to=<nramasurbramanian@localhost>, orig_to=<nramasurbramanian>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
2020-07-17T02:50:12.435720-07:00 localhost postfix/qmgr[1371]: 681EC1FFEF: removed
```

Same when I run normally in command line it works fine, getting below

```
2020-07-17T02:51:17.838476-07:00 localhost postfix/qmgr[1371]: CC8291FFEF: from=<support@test.com>, size=2239, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2020-07-17T02:51:19.016735-07:00 localhost postfix/smtp[27130]: CC8291FFEF: to=<in.support@test.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[108.177.127.27]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0/0.02/0.76/0.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1594979478 x17si5640395edq.338 - gsmtp)
2020-07-17T02:51:19.016905-07:00 localhost postfix/qmgr[1371]: CC8291FFEF: removed
```

Is there a default configuration which it is taking when running from crontab?

Answer (score 0):

After providing the absolute path of sendmail /usr/sbin/sendmail and set in crontab this is working fine.